# Boxes not centered using Angular Material directive

Tags: css, angular-material

Can anyone check the code above
I don't know why I can't put boxes in the middle with the directive `layout-align="center center"`? Thanks.

**Code snippet:**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .one {
      background: tomato;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
    .two {
      background: green;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="testApp">
  <div class="wrapper" layout-align="center center">
    <div class="container" layout-gt-xs="row" layout-xs="columnn" flex="none">
      <div class="one" flex="initial"></div>
      <div class="two" flex="initial"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("testApp", ["ngMaterial"]);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `layout-align="center center"` for the container instead of wrapper since flex works directly on the children. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/b9253hf0/

Comment: Thanks so much @ManojKumar, but why they are still not in the middle vertically?

Comment: Because you have given `flex-direction` as row for greater than `xs` screen size.

Comment: I tried to change it to column, still couldnt put them in the middle of screen. seems it's not about flex-direction. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment

Comment: I got it, just because I didn't set height for the container...

Comment: That's great. You can answer your question and mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @ManojKumar's answer, layout-align directive only affects immediate children.